# When do we have $L^p(X) = L^q(X)$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Let $1 < p < q < \infty$, is there an example such that $L^p(X) = L^q(X)$, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the trivial examples where the measure consists of finitely many atoms.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more, please? What do you mean finitely many atoms? Such as?

Comment: Atoms are measurable sets of positive measure such that no proper subset has positive measure.  For example, let $X$ be a finite set with counting measure.  Each member of $X$ is an atom.  If there are $n$ of these, then $L^p(X)$ is isomorphic to ${\mathbb R}^n$ (or ${\mathbb C}^n$, depending on your preference for scalars).

Comment: Pedantically speaking, each singleton subset of $X$ is an atom in that context.